# Extract confidence interval for a combination (sum) of variance estimates from a mixed model (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I use a mixed model to separate the variance of some measurement into between- and within group variance. The model looks like this:

```r
library(lme4)

k <- 100 
i <- 5

group_mean <- rnorm(k, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(k*i, rep(group_mean, each = i), 0.5)

df <- data.frame(y, group = rep(1:k, each = i))
    
m <- lmer(y ~ (1|group), data = df)
```

I can extract between- and within group SD and confidence intervals:

```r
VarCorr(m)
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  group    (Intercept) 0.99958 
#>  Residual             0.50327
confint(m, oldNames = FALSE)
#> Computing profile confidence intervals ...
#>                           2.5 %     97.5 %
#> sd_(Intercept)|group  0.8640826 1.15724604
#> sigma                 0.4703110 0.54026452
#> (Intercept)          -0.3782316 0.02526364
```

How can I get confidence intervals for the sum of the variances (`sd_(Intercept)|group^2 + sigma^2`)? I.e. the estimated variance in `y` with only one observation per `group`.

Comment: You could bootstrap it?

Comment: That could be the solution. I can see that confint() has the option to supply a custom boot function.

Comment: I would look into using `bootMer`.

Comment: After reading a bit of documentation, I can see that `confint()` can pass a model and custom function to `bootMer()`, and then calculate CI from the resulting bootstrap estimates (`confint(m, method = 'boot', FUN = get_total_sd, nsim = 10000)`). Works quite nicely, though it takes a few minutes for 10000 resamples of this simple dataset. Not unreasonable for my usecase though.

Comment: You are encouraged to self-answer your question based on this.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Roland, it is possible to bootstrap this. lme4 provides a nice framework for this:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

k <- 100 
i <- 5

group_mean <- rnorm(k, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(k*i, rep(group_mean, each = i), 0.5)

df <- data.frame(y, group = rep(1:k, each = i))

m <- lmer(y ~ (1|group), data = df)

get_total_sd <- function(mod) {
    varCorr_df <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(mod))
    sd_components <- varCorr_df[['sdcor']]
    names(sd_components) <- varCorr_df[['grp']]

    sd_total <- sqrt(sum(sd_components^2))

    c(sd_components, "Total" = sd_total)
}

confint(m, method = 'boot', FUN = get_total_sd, nsim = 10000)
#>              2.5 %    97.5 %
#> group    0.7655064 1.0329894
#> Residual 0.4921279 0.5657032
#> Total    0.9290245 1.1600250

confint(m, oldNames = FALSE)
#> Computing profile confidence intervals ...
#>                            2.5 %    97.5 %
#> sd_(Intercept)|group  0.77542074 1.0439971
#> sigma                 0.49426283 0.5677789
#> (Intercept)          -0.01914245 0.3472213
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The bootstrapped (percentile) CIs for the individual SDs are similar to the profiled, but not equal. I'm not sure which are better. This does take a few minutes to run, so I'm still interested in other approaches.